# Reading QR-code from webcam

Tags: java, qr-code

I am trying to read a QR-code from a piece of paper using a webcam but it keeps failing - it won't print. I have been stuck with this problem for several days now.

Here is my code:

public void imageUpdated(Image image)
    {

```
    LuminanceSource ls = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource((BufferedImage)image);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(ls));
    QRCodeReader qrReader = new QRCodeReader(); 
    try {
        Result result = qrReader.decode(bitmap);
        System.out.println("QR Code data is: "+result.getText());
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("--------");
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("--------");
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("--------");
    }
    qrReader.reset();
}
```

Does this code seem odd to anyone of you? Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: It depends on image quality. You cah try to add instruction 'try harder' into decode method: `Map<DecodeHintType, Void> hints = new TreeMap<>();
  hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, null); Result result = qrReader.decode(bitmap, hints );`

Comment: It still doesn't work.. But thank you for your answer :)

Comment: can you provide example of the image you are trying to decode?

Comment: I dont think so. It is a QR-code on a piece of paper "saying" north. Tried using the paper on different online QR-readers and they read the picture without problems :)

Comment: You'r passing BufferedImage to BufferedImageLuminanceSource. Try to output this image to file and post it somewhere.

Comment: Im not quite understanding what you want me to do, sry. Could you explain it in more depth?

Comment: I want to get an image which you try to decode

Comment: Okay, i have saved the file, but the picture is all black..

Comment: There is your problem! :)

Comment: Haha, it sure is!
Would you mind take a look at how I save the file? Just to be sure i dont mess anything up.
Here's the code:

BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) image;
  File f = new File("/Users/JacobWorckJepsen/Desktop/MyFile.JPEG");
  try {
   ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", f);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is correct code.

Comment: I will write my answer as soon as i can figure out what the hell is going on :) Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the method i used to convert my frame (Mat object) to a bufferedImage didn't work. The picture was all black. Found this code on StackOverflow which worked for me:

```
public Image toBufferedImage(Mat m){
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
    byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
    return image;
}
```